# linux shared library compatibility when using different gcc version

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

If a shared library is compiled with higher gcc version, is it promised to work when I use lower gcc version to compile my program and link with it? Suppose the shared library only depends on glibc and I am using the same glibc version.

Comment: Yes.  The change in `gcc` version should in general not be a problem.  It is however more common to provide the libraries with a the older compiler to be used by all newer ones.  Python wheels do something like that, as do other system where (C interface) libraries are used. You can also generally upgrade "forward" and have your existing libraries continue to work -- many linux distros work that way.